# Is $y' + ay^4 + b = 0$ elementary?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve a physics problem getting at the end this differential equation:
$$y' + ay^4 + b = 0$$

- This isn't a linear differential equation, so I need something tricky.
- It's really close to be [Bernoulli equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) but it isn't.

Is it possible to get elementary solutions? If so, hints are appreciated.

Comment: your differential equations textbook surely has a section on separable differential equations.  What do you get from that?

Comment: This idea works. As hjpotter92 wrote I get an easy form to integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have $ a $ and $ b $ constants, you can form a non-linear first order differential equation:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= - 1 \times \left( a y^4 + b \right) \\
\dfrac{dy}{a y^4 + b} &= - dx
\end{align}
$$

which can be integrated.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a negative in front of the dx?